# Sorting data by key value

Tags: arrays, json

I have a JSON file:

```
{
   "automotive_auto buying and selling_1_2":2.66883E-06,
   "automotive_auto infotainment technologies_1_9_1":8.67917E-06,
   "automotive_auto insurance_1_3":1.41038E-06,
   "automotive_auto navigation systems_1_9_2":1.13127E-05,

[...]

   "video gaming_simulation video games_29_5_11":3.81729E-06,
   "video gaming_sports video games_29_5_12":2.02059E-06,
   "video gaming_strategy video games_29_5_13":3.41502E-07
}
```

I need a JavaScript function to sort those numbers in descending order, and get the key whose number is the biggest, which here would first give:

```
1.13127e-05
8.67917e-06
3.81729e-06
2.66883e-06
2.02059e-06
1.41038e-06
3.41502e-07
```

And therefore I would get the corresponding key of the first result:

```
automotive_auto navigation systems_1_9_2
```

Is this possible?

Thank you so much for reading!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a json file you can read the data with `readFileSync` and then perform the `findHighest` function implemented below:

```
const fs = require("fs");

let jsDataArray = Object.entries(
  JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/file.json`, "utf8"))
);


const findHighest = (data) => {
  let result = data[0][1];
  let finalResult = data[0][0];
  data.forEach((item) => {
    if (item[1] > result) {
      result = item[1];
      finalResult = item[0];
    }
  });

  return finalResult;
};

console.log(findHighest(jsDataArray));
```

Note that this solution only gives the first result as you wanted and avoids the sorting giving a much faster run time because we are basically  iterating once.

Comment: This is the solution of the problem I described. Thank you so much for that. I want to point out however that I ended up using the solution from @zirmax because I realized it fit better my particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is to loop over the keys and store it to a variable if it is bigger than the current saved one:

```js
const obj = {
  "automotive_auto buying and selling_1_2": 1,
  "automotive_auto infotainment technologies_1_9_1": 3,
  "automotive_auto insurance_1_3": 5,
  "automotive_auto navigation systems_1_9_2": 1,

}

let maxKey = Object.keys(obj)[0]
for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
  if (obj[key] > obj[maxKey]) {
    maxKey = key
  }
}

console.log(maxKey, obj[maxKey])
```

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using, though for the solution of my exact problem, look out for the answer from @David Prifti. Thank you so much to the both of you!